# javascript fetching an API json rest cannot access the data

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, fetch-api

This is driving crazy, I have a API JSON rest that I can access perfectly from the Firefox extension </> RESTED and directly from the browser I can see the data but when I tried my code it said:

> "code: "rest_cannot_access", message: "Only authenticated users can access the REST API.".

So I don't understand why.

It's a WordPress rest API plugin, and I tried to get the data from fetch JavaScript. This is the URL http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

This is my code to test:

```
fetch('http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(data)
    })
```

Comment: I cannot access this information directly from the browser, I also get an authentication error. So the api must require credentials to be sent along with the request. You probably have an authentication cookie saved for the website on your browser.

Comment: @CalIrvine yes Cal you're right, I just checked in other pc and I got the same error "can't access". So should I need a auth wordpress plugin just to access (GET)? cuz' I don't want to do any post or delete, I just want to get the data. Thanks

Comment: I don't know the particulars of the WP rest api, but maybe this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265523/wp-rest-api-require-password-for-get-endpoint stackexchange question will help? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look here https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

For sure you are logged in by a cookie. Try to open a "private browser window" and you will get the same error.

Comment: Thank you very much